# Bulk update in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, bulkupdate

I need to update one table records based on another one.

I tried

```
update      currencies
set         priority_order= t2.priority_order
from        currencies t1
inner join  currencies1 t2
on          t1.id = t2.id
```

but is giving error (same query work for MySQL and SQL Server).

Then I tried below:

```
update      currencies
set         priority_order= (select 
                            priority_order 
                            from currencies1 
                            where 
                            currencies.id=currencies1.id
                           )
```

It is working but is very slow, I need to do it for some big tables as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, this would look something like:

```
update currencies t1
    set priority_order = t2.priority_order
    from currencies1 t2
    where t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: You could add `AND t1.priority_order IS DISTINCT FROM t2.priority_order` to the WHERE clause to avoid creating unnecessary row-versions.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE currencies dst
   SET priority_order = src.priority_order
  FROM currencies src
 WHERE dst.id = src.id
   -- Suppress updates if the value does not actually change
   -- This will avoid creation of row-versions
   -- which will need to be cleaned up afterwards, by (auto)vacuum.
AND  dst.priority_order IS DISTINCT FROM src.priority_order
        ;
```

Testing (10K rows, after cache warmup), using the same table for both source and target for the updates:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 10000
VACUUM
Timing is on.
cache warming:
UPDATE 0
Time: 16,410 ms
zero-rows-touched:
UPDATE 0
Time: 8,520 ms
all-rows-touched:
UPDATE 10000
Time: 84,375 ms
```

Normally you will seldomly see the case of no rows affected, neither the case with all rows affected. But with only 50% of the rows touched, the query would still be twice as fast. (plus the reduced work for vacuum *after* the query)